# Okular: Text disappears after it has been highlighted

Tags: okular

In Okular, as soon as I highlight (you get the tool by pressing F6 and then 4) the text, the whole text of the page disappears. However, this happens only on some PDFs.

I googled to find a fix for this but I found nothing. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

The following GIF may help you to see my problem:

[image]

EDIT: I added another GIF, which shows the problem in more detail:

[image]

Comment: By highlighting, do you mean selecting text using the "Text Selection Tool"? I found the same pdf and, at least with the Text Selection Tool, I don't see anything disappearing. I have okular 4.16 and plasma 5.8.7 on 16.04 (http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports).

Comment: It's the tool you get, when you press F6 and then the number 4. It will highlight the text. I think, it's not the text selection tool, since you can see it afterwards yellow. It's a text marker.

Comment: I'll try your F6, 4 route. And it does exactly what you describe. Maybe you could file a bug. You may want to ask at https://forum.kde.org/index.php in case such a bug has already been filed.

Comment: The weird thing is, it only happens for some PDFs. Are there maybe some settings, which could cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Workaround:

The problem is described here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360201

A solution is proposed by azzamsa, which worked for me:

> azzamsa 2016-03-11 10:06:03 UTC
>
> [SOLVED]
>
> prolem solved using pdfchain, no any configuration needed, just using
>   default configuration from pdfchain, save as it somewhere, and I can
>   add the annotation, okular works  well for this pdf output from
>   pdfchain, okular save the xml correctly, ( not like before, the xml
>   are not written correctly)
>
> update1 : select "repair document" and content list (bookmar list)
>   will preserved.